# Routing problem on my Symfony project on Apache

Tags: apache, symfony

I looked at different topic regarding my problem but it still doesn't work.

I have just deployed my website in Symfony, on my Debian with Apache.
I manage to go to the main page, but the others return me a 404 error.

I saw that it was necessary to add the .htaccess file for the routing, something that I did but it still does not work.

But when I enter the url: `https://myWebsite/index.php/movie` it works.

(Tell me if you need more code)

EDIT : on the url `https://myWebsite.fr` the Symfony Tool Bar doesnt work, the error in the console is : `https://mywebsite.fr/_wdt/af9d59`

RESOLVED : I added the allowoverride in my HTTPS .conf and its working.

There is my website.conf on my Apache folder "sites-available" :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
# The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
# the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
# redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
# specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
# match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
# value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
# However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
ServerName mywebsite.fr

ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/project/public

<Directory /var/www/project/public>
    AllowOverride All
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from All
</Directory>

# Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
# error, crit, alert, emerg.
# It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
# modules, e.g.
#LogLevel info ssl:warn

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/project_error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/projec_access.log combined

# For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
# enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
# include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
# following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
# after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
#Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =mywebsite.fr
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

My second .conf *mywebsite-le-ssl* for the https (using certbot) :

`

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>     
# The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and   port that
# the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
# redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the   ServerName
# specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host:   header to
# match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this   file) this
# value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host  regardless.
# However, you must set it for any further virtual host  explicitly.
ServerName mywebsite.fr

ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/mywebsite/public

# Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
# error, crit, alert, emerg.
# It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
# modules, e.g.
#LogLevel info ssl:warn

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/project_error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/projec_access.log combined

# For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
# enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
# include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
# following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
# after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
#Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
RewriteEngine on
# Some rewrite rules in this file were disabled on your HTTPS site,
# because they have the potential to create redirection loops.

# RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =mywebsite.fr
# RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]


 SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite.fr/fullchain.pem
 SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite.fr/privkey.pem
 Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
 </VirtualHost>
 </IfModule>
```

`

Comment: I found my problem, the site works in HTTP but not in HTTPS, I don't know why yet

Comment: You can do `composer require symfony/apache-pack` this will create the correct *.htaccess* for you. Your vhost file doesn't have a https (443) directive, `eg. <VirtualHost *:443>...`

Comment: I've already used this command, this command created the .htaccess in my public folder. Yes my bad I got a second .conf with the 443, I add this file in my topic

Comment: You don't have a allowoverride statement in your 443 vhost, that might be your problem. Also for some reason you have a different documentroot

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Thanks you so much, thats was that, I've just added the allowoverride in the https .conf !

Comment: This is resolve but to answer, I had a problem with routing my site over HTTPS, it just wasn't working.